# When I am clicking the 1st button the 2nd button triggered but disappears immediately using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am using Pygame. I need to trigger the 2nd button after clicking 1st button and 2nd button should stay on screen until further actions on it.

Here is the part of code where I am stucked:

```
if start_button.draw(17, 315, 'START', font_size=15):
    test_button.draw(17, 415, 'TEST BUTTON', font_size=15)
```

I have created `test_button` in order to test if the 2nd button will appear after clicking the `start_button`. For now `test_button` is created but unfortunately it disapears immediately and does not stay on screen like a `start_button`. I can't understand the reason. Probably I did something wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but do something like this:

1. Make an **instance variable** inside of your button called active .
   So something like this:

   ```py
   class Button:
       def __init__(self):
           self.active = False
   ```
2. Do:

   ```py
   if start_button.draw(17, 315, 'START', font_size=15):
       test_button.active = True
   ```
3. And then put an if statement to check if it is active.

   ```py
   If test_button.active:
        test_button.draw(17, 415, 'TEST BUTTON', font_size=15)
   ```

Comment: Please read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks for reply @CozyCode. But this solution is not working for me. Nothing happened after clicking to button. It is my code after your help. Am I correcly understand you or I am missing something? 

if start_button.draw(17, 315, 'START', font_size=15): 
    test_button.active = True
    If test_button.active:
     test_button.draw(17, 415, 'TEST BUTTON', font_size=15)

Comment: Are you sure "if start_button.draw(17, 315, 'START', font_size=15)" checks if your pressing the button or not?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Since I have created class Button and defined variable for click using get_pressed(). Draw function is inside of this class. Moreover, its already tested and working fine. Just impossible to trigger stable test_button by clicking the start_button and its very strange.

Comment: "if test_button.active:" gets executed every frame right?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. "If test_button.active" I have used only once after your suggestion. Before I have used only "if test_button.draw". I need to trigger the test button by clicking to start button, and test_button should stay on the screen. But currently test button is not stable, however the similar one (start button) stay stable on the screen and waiting for further actions on it. So, can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but with this little information I don't think I can help you